# WP8 Map control with custom tiles

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to display a map control in my app targeting Windows Phone 8 but I want to use custom tiles from open street map.

I'm using this line :

```
mapControl.TileSources.Add(new TileSource("http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{zoomLevel}/{x}/{y}.png"));
```

When I launch the app the custom tiles are properly displayed, but there's still the default map tiles underneath them.

I tried to hide them, but I counld'nt even find where they exist in the map control and what is displaying them exactly.

I would like to know how I can remove those default tiles when loading custom tiles.

I tried to hide them, but I counld'nt even find where they exist in the map control and what is displaying them exactly.

PS : Here's the link to the "old" bing map control if you cannot find it in the latest WP Tools : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=2949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this myself with the new WP8 "Nokia HERE maps" map control but was unable to achieve this. I had to resort to falling back to the older "Bing" based map control in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps (marked as obsolete).

Here's how to remove the other layers in the older Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps control:

```
for (var i = Map.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    MapTileLayer tileLayer = Map.Children[i] as MapTileLayer;
    if (tileLayer != null)
    {
        Map.Children.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Even though this older map control has been superseded in WP8 the newer control doesn't seem to support the same flexibility with layers and the "obsolete" control still works happily under WP8.1 if used in your app.

Here's my app which still uses the older control which is probably achieving what you're trying to do - [NZ Topo Map app for Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/store/app/nz-topo-map/b861ab51-a68d-456f-9ae4-cbed66736b36).

Cut down Xaml for using the older map control in your app (you'll probably want to ignore my data bindings and replace them with your own):

```
<UserControl x:Class="TopoMap.Controls.Map"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <m:Map x:Name="MapBase" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" ScaleVisibility="Visible"
               Loaded="Map_Loaded"
               LayoutUpdated="Map_LayoutUpdated"
               ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
               Center="{Binding Center, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </m:Map>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

The important reference that you need it:

```
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"
```

Comment: The point is that I'm using a new installation of visual studio 2013 with the latest tools and I can't find this namespace anywhere (Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps) Looks like it has been removed in the latest tools.

Comment: Maybe you're developing a WP8.1 app instead of WP8 app? Your tags state "windows-phone-8". There's quite a difference between the two platforms regarding what's available.

Comment: I'm developing for Windows 8.0 and as I thought, the Control is not available anymore in the tools but I could find it as a standalone download. I'll post the link in my original question if someone needs it.

Comment: The control should still be available to you as it's part of the 8.0 framework. I'm updating my answer with the XAML so you can copy the relevant namespaces etc. from it.

Comment: The dll was actually present on disk but not appearing in Visual Studio when I was trying to add a reference. I had to hit browse and then go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries\ in order to find it. Thanks anyway, I'll use the old control then.